# Adding delay to function during drawing objects

Tags: javascript, html, loops

i placed setInterval into the code but this obviously delaying all the lasers by 1 second.  
I want it to be working in the following sequence: 
- at start laser1 and laser2 are fired. 
- 1 second break and fire another set of lasers etc.

Also if someone could teach me how to move all block of code by four spaces on forum, that would be amazing, as none of the ways i found in google solve this ridiculous problem.

Code shortcut:

```
let laser1;
let lasers1 = [];
let laser2;
let lasers2 = [];

function createLaser() {
    laser1 = new Laser(bossOne.x, bossOne.y + bossOne.sizeY, 10, 50, 5);
    lasers1.push(laser1);
    laser2 = new Laser(bossOne.x + bossOne.sizeX - 10, bossOne.y + 
    bossOne.sizeY, 10, 50, 5);
    lasers2.push(laser2);
}


function draw() {
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

setInterval(createLaser, 1000);

for (i = 0; i < lasers1.length; i++) {
    lasers1[i].show();
    lasers1[i].move();
}
for (i = 0; i < lasers2.length; i++) {
    lasers2[i].show();
    lasers2[i].move();
}

}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Remote host for full code if needed:
https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/ 
lasers are red

I think i should work with booleans, but can't handle to set it there. 
Got a similar topic with key activation, but i lost contact with the one who proposed a solution on the basis of booleans (as it didn't work well) so i took the easiest part first without involving the keys.

Any tips are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `setInterval` to `setTimeout`, as it's already looping recursively - just add a delay to it. Also move the `requestAnimationFrame` call to the bottom of `draw`, not the top:

```
function draw()
    setTimeout(createLasers, 1000);
    //Loops
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Comment: solved it, set Interval has to be used as it needs to be repeated constantly, also the object creation has to be placed out of the draw loop